# How do i set a background to all radio buttons in all radio groups in Android

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make all radio groups with red background and all radio buttons with white background. With this code, all radio groups get the red background, but only the last for 4 radio buttons get the white background. What can i do, to set the white background to all radio buttons, from all radio groups?
Here is my code:

```
    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                radioGroup[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    radioButton[j].setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `radioButton` array is never changed. It has the same value as it was before entering the loop. Try this:

```
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            radioGroup[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As I do not know your remaining code, you may find a smarter way of accessing the first three radioButton arrays.

Comment: you want to use `j` as counter for child in the second loop

Comment: Doesn't work. Only the first radio button from the first radio group gets the white background, from the second radio group, only the second radio button gets the white background, from third radio group, only the third radio button gets the white background and from the fourth, only the fourth radio button gets the white background.

Comment: @AlexM. well, see JonnyAW's hint and try it again.

Comment: It is `i` for `radioGroup[]`and `j`for `getChildAt()`

Comment: There will be no problem, but what means an 'accept'? I'm new here.

Comment: There are outlined ticks for you under each upvote/downvote thing on the top left of the questions. When you find one answer does provide you with the correct solution of your problem then you mark it as correct (accepting the answer) by clicking on that tick icon. This shows others the correct answer to your question when they find your question by searching for a solution for their problem. And it earns credits for the one who gave the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to define background in both radioGroup and radioButton in xml with following attribute :-

android:background="#FF0000"

It will give you red background to your radio group. And

android:background="#FFFFFF"

It will give you white background for your radio buttons. Note you need to define this attribute in all buttons if you want them so.

Comment: Apparently he wants to do this dynamically as reaction on some click. How would you do that in XML?

Comment: @Hermann Hmm, I don't see if OP has written to do so dynamically.

Comment: Thanks but i need it dynamically.